# CloudFormation Template not able to install R related packages

Tags: r, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create an EC2 instance through CloudFormation template where I am trying to install Zeppelin,Spark & R as shown [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-big-data-blog/blob/master/aws-blog-zeppelin-yarn-on-ec2/zeppelin-yarn-on-ec2.json)...now I want to install R related packages..so in the "**Install**" section,my template looks as follows:

```
"AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
      "configSets" : {
        "InstallAndRun" : [ "Install", "Configure" ]
      },

      "Install" : {
        "packages" : {
          "yum" : {
            "git"          : [],
            "java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64": [],
            "R R-devel": [],
            "libpng"              : [],
            "libpng-devel"                    : [],
            "curl curl-devel"                     : [],
            "libxml2 libxml2-devel"                   : []
          }
        },
```

But it is only able to install git & java....i saw in the logs where the error message was "**Unhandled exception during build: Yum does not have libxml2 libxml2-devel available for installation**" ..so what needs to be done for that ?? What are the packages required for installing R via CloudFormation ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using invalid syntax. Each yum package needs to be specified separately, so change:

```
        "R R-devel": [],
        "curl curl-devel"                     : [],
        "libxml2 libxml2-devel"                   : []
```

to something like:

```
        "R": [],
        "R-devel": [],
        "curl": [],
        "curl-devel": [],
        "libxml2": [],
        "libxml2-devel": []
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because these packages are not in the base yum repo.  You can find them in the EPEL yum repo.  Try passing `--enablerepo=epel` when you install these packages.